# How does sort() work in data.frame within R

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

How does `sort` work, that is using what method to sort column in

```
data.frame (barley$site, barley$year, barley$variety)
```

as following

```
library(lattice)
barley <- barley[order(barley$site, barley$year, barley$variety), ]
```

Comment: `?sort()` will be a good place to start...

Comment: Additionally, `sort` and `order` are not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want:

```
barley[order(as.character(barley$site), as.numeric(barley$year), as.character(barley$variety)),]
```

As you have it you are ordering by the underlying levels of the data.frame, which leads to really odd stuff.  Look at the structure of the data frame:

```
 'data.frame':  120 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ yield  : num  27 48.9 27.4 39.9 33 ...
 $ variety: Factor w/ 10 levels "Svansota","No. 462",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 7 7 7 7 ...
 $ year   : Factor w/ 2 levels "1932","1931": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ site   : Factor w/ 6 levels "Grand Rapids",..: 3 6 4 5 1 2 3 6 4 5 ...
```

Notice how the levels for `year` are in the opposite order you would expect.  The documentation for `order` discusses this very briefly:

> For factors, this sorts on the internal codes, which is particularly appropriate for ordered factors.

I personally think this terribly confusing, but it is what it is.  factor are very useful in most contexts, but incredibly dangerous in others if you're not careful.  Having numbers represented as factors (as `year` was here) is particularly bad.

See `?factor` for more details.

Comment: ThX, but I want to know if I didn't add as.blah, why the order() doesn't sort barley$site alphabetically.

Comment: @user3363145, did you read my explanation?  In particular, look at the level orders.  For example, "Grand Rapids" is the first one in the `site` vector, and "1932" the first one in the `year` vector, which is why those turn up first.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `sort` doesn't know how to do anything with a data frame. You can sort the individual columns within a data frame, with something like `df$x <- sort(df$x)` but you almost certainly don't want to do that; it will just mess up your data.

You order the rows in the data frame by using `order` as in the example code you have there. This orders the rows by values in the column `site`, breaking ties with `year`, and then with `variety`.